# Cassandra: what is the most scalable data model for managing tags?

Tags: cassandra

I am a bit confused about the best approach to manage tags the Cassandra way: string field? array field? secondary index? wide columns? or even compound ids?

I currently think an array field+secondary index will be a good fit. 
better option considering ability to scale?

links to achieve full confusion ^_^ :

- http://fr.slideshare.net/edanuff/indexing-in-cassandra
- http://fr.slideshare.net/jaykumarpatel/cassandra-data-modeling-best-practices?next_slideshow=2

Addition about the data itself - It is very similar to Stack Overflow tags:

- 0- the data: each row is simple text written in HTML (very simple, no answsers to store, no 1-n relation) plus other basic info(eg. usage statitics): its size is small (below 1k)
- 1- there is a fixed category list (total like 50 categories): **so each tag is defined within a category area.**
- 2- then there is "user defined" unlimited tags per row that is be used for autosuggestion, search by tag, list through tag, count, the whole filtered by the category
- the search by tags could use random mutliple tags: list all of the rows that match a set of tags

I konw how to do this using couchDB/Couchbase, It is very easy. So far Cassandra is very confusing because we never know what is the recommended model, unless digging into internals.

Note, the current CF is like :

```
CREATE TABLE items (
    id timeuuid,
    user_id uuid,
    name varchar,
    description text,
    tags set<text>,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Like most things in Cassandra, it really depends on your queries, and data size. Can one tag have values that go over one or a few hundred meg? In that case, you'll want to bucket within a tag. Are you trying to look up values for two tags together? In that case, you might create a tag out of multiple tags. This is assuming simple text tags.

With huge data sets, simply having tags-> values may not be a good option. You might then want to use a potentially separate phase with some form of locality sensitive hashing to figure out which buckets to consider. Usually, Cassandra will do a good job of managing partitions. However, with many many tags, and not extremely large values, it might be worth LHS with prefix / length / prefix+suffix length etc. to minimise the number of tags.

There are many different ways this can be solved, but whether it's appropriate for your scenario depends on...well...your scenario. If you give us your expected queries and expected number of tags / values, we would be able to help a bit more.

Comment: It is very similar to Stack Overflow tags:

- 0 the data are simple questions written in HTML (very simple, no answsers to store, no 1-n relation) 

- 1 there is a fixed category list (total like 50 categories)

- 2- then there is "user defined" unlimited tag that is be used for autosuggestion & search by tag, list through tag, the whole filtered by the category

Comment: How many documents per tag do you expect? Autosuggest type things in Cassandra are generally difficult, and pairing with Solr or Elastic Search may be a good idea for searching. Cassandra does exact matches on keys.

Comment: I think thanks to this http://solr-vs-elasticsearch.com/ that  ElasticSearch is the best option